# Retrofit access to list withouth reference

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have this JSON and when trying to access the list I don't know how to pass the value "Serialized", I don't have any value.
I work on android.
Does anyone know how to access?
Thank you.

```
[
    {
        "id": “111”,
        "dateStart": "2020-02-26T00:00:00+01:00",
        "dateEnd": "2020-02-26T01:30:00+01:00",
        "sectionId": 0,
        "description": “Test”,
        "comment": “Test comment”,
        "emissionType": “A”,
        "priority": 5,
        "audios": [],
        "idCollection": “1”
    },
    {
        "id": “222”,
        "dateStart": "2020-02-26T00:00:00+01:00",
        "dateEnd": "2020-02-26T01:30:00+01:00",
        "sectionId": 0,
        "description": “Test”,
        "comment": “Test comment”,
        "emissionType": “B”,
        "priority": 5,
        "audios": [],
        "idCollection": “12”
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Gson getGSONBuilder() 
{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().
            registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new JsonSerializer<Double>() 
    {

                @Override
                public JsonElement serialize(Double src, Type typeOfSrc, 
                 JsonSerializationContext context) {
                    if (src == src.longValue())
                        return new JsonPrimitive("" + src.longValue());
                    return new JsonPrimitive("" + src);
                }
            }).create();

    return gson;
}
String responseString=getGSONBuilder().toJson(response.body());//response is Retrofit 
response
```

Answer (score 0):

in retrofit just call the ArrayList> in responce you get all the arraylist data into hashmap with its key and value .

```
for(int i=0;i<responce.body().size;i++){
arrlist.add(responce.body().get(i))
 }
```